# emptying Url Key when duplicating product

Tags: magento-1.9, duplicate

I'm looking for a way to completely empty out the Url Key when a product is duplicated.

i've already tried:

```
 $newProduct->setUrlKey(NULL);
```

in a rewrite of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product.
but this just results in magento regenerating the Url Key.

i also read [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111695/magento-using-duplicate-product-button-but-emptying-url-key) question but there is no answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try it by changing core file?

Comment: @SukumarGorai Yes i rewrote Mage_Catalog_Model_Product

Comment: I am not asking about rewrite. Did you try by changing the core file?

Comment: @SukumarGorai No i didn't, isn't chaning core files considered very bad practice?

Comment: Yes its bad practice but need to confirm its working on core or not.